# React-Native app doesn't work properly with external packages

Tags: react-native

It works very normally when I use React Hooks or when I use react-native's Component, Hooks.
But when I call a function or Component from external packages such as Axios from my code, the app seems to be broken in that state. (or an empty screen)
I used react-native-cli.

```js
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import type {Node} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
  Center,
} from 'react-native';
import Axios from 'axios';

import {
  Colors,
  Header,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

const App: () => Node = () => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
      const {data} = await Axios.get(...); // broken
      setText(data.result);
    };
    fetch();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'} />
      <ScrollView
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        style={backgroundStyle}>
        <Header />
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          }}>
          <Text>{text}</Text>
          {/*
            this Text Component is still empty.
          */}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try to import axios with the first letter as lower case

Comment: It was the same when I changed first letter to lowercase letter.

Comment: Post your errors so